# UpdatePanel with AsyncPostback tryes to update control outside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to have `UpdatePanel` with `asyncpostback`, but in my case it seems that no partial postback happens, but fullpostback. I am new to web forms, please, check the code:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Cust" TagName="CompanyInformationView" Src="~/CustomControls/CompanyInformationView.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick= "Button1_Click" Text="test" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <Cust:CompanyInformationView ID="CompanyInformationView" runat="server" />   
</asp:Content>
```

So I have `Test Button.` `OnClick` it should do "nothing" for test. Also there is custom control on web form. Here is server side code for this form:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       // fill in custom control
       CompanyInfo c = GetInfo();
       CompanyInformationView.Company = c;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var i = 1;
}
```

`CompanyInformationView` is custom control with property "`Company`". There is no `ViewState` added for this property (so it cannot be loaded properly if postback is done). When I click on `Test Button`, the page fails, because "`CompanyInformationView.Company`" is not set (it is not set, because it cannot be loaded from ViewState, I guess).

Instead, I think that it should not work like this. `AsynPostback` should deal only with `UpdatePanel`.

Why it wants to reload `custom control`? Doesn't it mean that Full postback happen or maybe I do not understand Asyncpostback?

Answer (score 0):

PageLoad and all other events are raised on every get\postback, no matter if it's async or full,
In asyncpostback, the response which the server renders includes only the content inside the updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>`

Before

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Comment: But I already have one scriptmanager somewhere on above level.

Answer (score 0):

Async post back in web forms still proceeds the whole page life cycle as if it's a traditional post. the difference is only the updated content inside target update panel that will be sent in response. so in this case, async post back will still give you exception unless you populate the custom control no matter get/post.

you need to also put the custom control inside another update panel or in the same update panel as the button in order see partial update to happen.